# ImportError: Python + GDAL - OSGeo4W installation

Tags: python, windows-7-x64, gdal, osgeo

I have installed the latest compilation of OSGeo4W for Windows and I want to use the various GDAL tools available. When I open the OSGeo4W *command shell*, enter Python and write

```
> from osgeo import gdal
```

I get the following error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 21,
> in <module>
>     _gdal = swig_import_helper()
>   File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 17,
> in swig_import_helper
>     _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The operating system cannot run %1.
```

My **PATH** contains the following OSGeo4W entries:

```
> C:\OSGeo4W\bin
> C:\OSGeo4W\\apps\msys\bin
> C:\OSGeo4W\\apps\Python27\Scripts
```

From what I read around the web, this error could be about incompatible versions. I assume that the OSGeo4W package is compiled to work as it is, thus it might be other versions previously installed on my computer or residues that interferes. But I don't know how to determine whats interfering and where that information is stored.

**What can I do to solve this problem?**

Answer (score 4):

This problem occurs when there's another version of python installed.

I found that when I added the directory path to `C:\OSGeo4W\bin` at the beginning of the `PATH` variable, and ran python through the `OSGEO4W` shell, that I was able to import the `gdal` library.

Comment: worked perfectly. Saved me tons of time trying other "fixes". hope it doesn't affect my arcgis python though!

Answer (score 1):

Shared libraries are not commonly stored in the `bin` subdirectories of a distribution. Try and dig through the source of `OSGeo4W` to locate the gdal dll file (`gdal.dll`??). Probably it is in a `lib` subdirectory. Add that path also to your `PATH` environment variable. If you want to check for other GDAL installs, just start a system wide search for the dll you try load and see if there are more than one.

---

Another option I found online for this error is that you need to use a specific Python version that is shipped with OSGeo4W. Using a normal Python 2.7 install will not work. See:

- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10173/how-to-import-qgis-core-in-a-osgeo4w-installation
- http://old.nabble.com/Python-bindings-to-OGR-td29827795.html

Comment: Well the files `gdal15.dll` - `gdal19.dll` is stored within `OSGeo4W\bin` which is already added to the path. I have searched through my system and found various `gdal#.dll` but none of them are located within any of the folders in my **PATH**.

Comment: As far as I know, I only have the OSGeo4W embedded Python installed (2.7.2). I wonder if this has anything to do with x86/x64?

Comment: Are you using a 64 bit OS? And OSGeo4W, is that 32 or 64 bit? Although 32 bit software should run on a 64 bit OS...

Comment: It seems like the OSGeo4W package is for x86 and there is only one installer on the *osgeo website*. And yes, I am using Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Maybe post a question on the mailing list of OSGeo.

Comment: If you get good results back from the mailing list, could you also post them here?